# addChild to each xml element

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file that looks like this:

```
...
   <offers>
      <offer>
               ...
      <offer>
      <offer>
               ...
      <offer>
      <offer>
               ...
      <offer>
   <offers>
...
```

I want to use "addChild" function on every "offer", so I'm using this code:

```
$xmlstr = simplexml_load_file('/file_location/test.xml'); 
$item = $xmlstr->shop->offers->offer->addChild('sales_notes', 'some value');

$xmlstr2 = '/file_location/test.xml';
file_put_contents($xmlstr2, $xmlstr->asXML());
```

This code only adds 'sales_notes' child to the first 'offer'. How can I add 'sales_notes' child to all 'offer' elements without using a lot of code?
Thanks!

Comment: use loop ... ..

Comment: @BilalAhmed I'm wondering if there is an another simple way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is loop through your `$xmlstr` and add the child.

Every item in `$xmlstr->shop->offers->offer` is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)

For example:

```
foreach($xmlstr->shop->offers->offer as $element) {
    $element->addChild('sales_notes', 'some value');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through it with getChildren.

```
foreach($xmlstr->shop->offers->getChildren() as $name => $data) {
    if ($name == "offer") ...
}
```

There is no magic one liner for that.